# vuejs app deploy to aws with eb cli. Error on instance Following services are not running: application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a vuejs app that I am trying to deploy to aws via elastic beanstalk cli. I get the error `Following services not running: application` and I'm not sure what that means. when I look at the logs I get

```
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the start script 'node build/dev-server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ntertainus package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build/dev-server.js
```

This is the first time I have tried to use the cli and hoping someone can help me out I would appreciate that a lot

here is my the part of the `package.json` file that I think is failing

```javascript
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm start",
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs test/e2e/specs"
},
```